# How to customise permalinks in Vuepress / Vuepress blog plugin?

Tags: vuepress

Currently, [Vuepress permalinks](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/permalinks.html#permalinks-2) are customisable only on the given template variables. For example, given the following directory structure:

```
posts
  coding
    my_post.md
```

and using permalink `/:regular` I get `/posts/coding/my_post.md`. However, due to migration and existing SEO issues, I need this link to be `/coding/my_post.md`. Is there a way to change the links that are generated in [Vuepress blog plugin](https://vuepress-plugin-blog.ulivz.com/guide/getting-started.html#directory-classifier)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no clear way for customising the permalinks generated from Vuepress or Vuepress blog plugin beyond the template variables. A solution I found was to use a custom plugin that set the permalink to exactly what I needed:

```js
module.exports = {
  extendPageData(pageCtx) {
    // We will force permalinks on the posts to be mapped
    // to root of the site. So /posts/my_post.md becomes /my_post.html
    if (pageCtx.path.startsWith("/posts")) {
      pageCtx.frontmatter.permalink = pageCtx.path.replace("/posts", "");
    }
  }
};
```

And use the plugin following the guidelines available on the [Plugins page](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/#examples). This solution works because Vuepress [respects the permalink frontmatter](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/frontmatter.html). I recommend reading more on the [plugin options API](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/plugin/option-api.html#extendpagedata) where there is more documentation how to extend page data and in this case modify permalinks.